# Can I avoid <SSRProvider> with react-bootstrap and Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

I've recently converted a WordPress + Bootstrap 5 website to Next.js (v12.2.2) and it's my first time using it. It's been pretty smooth sailing and I'd very much like the option of statically generating the site.

However, when using certain components of [React-Boostrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) (v2.5.0), I get the following warning when Next builds:

> When server rendering, you must wrap your application in an  to ensure consistent ids are generated between the client and server.

According to React-Bootstrap's [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/server-side-rendering/) this is because:

> React-Bootstrap automatically generates an id for some components (such as DropdownToggle) if they are not provided. This is done for accessibility purposes.

But even if I explicitly provide an ID, like in the example below, I still get the warning:

```js
<NavDropdown title="Menu" id="menu-dropdown"  active={/^\/thing-/.test(asPath)}>
    {[{
        title: 'Child 1',
        url: '/thing-is-awesome'
    },{
        title: 'Child 2',
        url: '/thing-is-good'
    }].map(i => (
        <NavDropdown.Item href={i.url + '/'} active={isActive(i.url)} key={i.url}>
            {i.title}
        </NavDropdown.Item>
    ))}
</NavDropdown>
```

Is there any way to avoid this issue that doesn't require me to wrap my entire app in an `<SSRProvider>`?

Comment: hey man, any luck?